# make preview of uploaded file

Tags: python, html, flask

How to make preview of uploaded file on Flask? I can get name of the file by printing it on the console, but how to preview it on html page?

`html:`

```
    <input type='file' class="hidden form-control" name="file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1" name="upload" class="form-control">Select Document</label>

my file is: {{ file }}
```

`python:`

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
file = request.form['file']
print(file)
return render_template('profile.html',file=file)
```

Comment: What isn't working? Any errors?

Comment: @12944qwerty, I do not know how to do it

Comment: Also, I noticed that you didn't indent the function for profile, is this a copying mistake?

Comment: @12944qwerty, yes, it just copying mistake

Comment: Answering `I do not know how to do it` doesn't help. Have you tried doing anything yet?

Comment: @12944qwerty, yes. please check the answer again.

Comment: i guess you need to perform `Ajax` requests, `POST` to upload the file in `/tmp` folder and then resend it back to the page with `GET` until confirmation from user (the `submit` button of the `form`) if OK you move the uploaded file from `/tmp` folder to `/uploads`

Comment: @cizario could you send some Ajax samples?